# Juju bootstrap on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: juju

My virtual lab via virt-manager:

- MAAS server
- JUJU controller

  but after the bootstrap, using the following command:

  $: juju bootstrap maas-cloud maas-cloud-controller --debug
  ....
  ....
  ....

I've received an error:

```
13:00:20 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:776 failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: unexpected: ServerError: 400 Bad Request ({"distro_series": ["'**bionic**' is not a valid distro_series.  It should be one of: '', 'ubuntu/focal'."]})
```

All lab is based on Ubuntu 20.04 and I can't understand because it signed me "bionic" when it isn't present.... On MAAS is set the 20.04
[image]

someone can explain me that thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is that:

```
juju bootstrap --bootstrap-series=focal maas-cloud maas-cloud-controller --debug
```

[image]